# iPhone - Slide Menu (UITableView) over current UIView with blur effect

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview, menu, push

I would like to add to my current application a menu which "slides" over the current UIView. I want to use a `UITableView` for the menu. It should look like the old Facebook-App. If you tap the menu Button on the top left, the menu should slide from left into the screen. But not like the Facebook app, the menu should not "push" the other view away, it should slide over the whole `UIView`. It would be great if someone could help me how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

No need to code that your self. Look for a library that can help you accomplish this. For example:

- **https://github.com/ECSlidingViewController/ECSlidingViewController**

Comment: Does Apple allow this library for the App Store?

Comment: @Mike_NotGuilty yes of course this is just one of the many simple ones. there is no private API